# PHP: Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out error

Tags: php, router, portforwarding, dmz

I have Worked out what is causing the issue but I don't know what I need to do to fix it.
I updated the parent router and my code stopped working.
figured it was just a new IP issue so fixed that but still wouldn't work. ran the code manually and got the issue

> Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection timed out error

This code creates a web address that when sent updates my solar recordings.
I remote into the PI from my house and can paste the link in the browser and it works fine but something stopping it on the device itself.

I narrowed it down to the new router somehow blocking my script from sending a link.
I chucked the device into DMZ on the router and it works fine...
guessing I need to open some ports or allow something but don't know what. I don't want to keep the device in DMZ

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a programming question. Ask on [su]

Comment: Ok thanks. Wasn't sure where it should have gone TBH